# Exception for add document variable(I cant figure out)

Tags: vb.net, openxml

I cant figure out where is my error is.Below is my code and the exception:

```
    Imports DocumentFormat.OpenXml
    Imports DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging
    Imports DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing

Public Class Form1

Public Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    'Create a word file
    Using wordDocument As WordprocessingDocument = WordprocessingDocument.Create("C:\Users\local\Desktop\vb testing purpose\test.docx", WordprocessingDocumentType.Document)
        ' Add a main document part. 
        Dim mainPart As MainDocumentPart = wordDocument.AddMainDocumentPart()
        ' Create the document structure and add some text.
        mainPart.Document = New Document()

        Dim body As Body = mainPart.Document.AppendChild(New Body())
        Dim para As Paragraph = body.AppendChild(New Paragraph())
        Dim run As Run = para.AppendChild(New Run())
        run.AppendChild(New Text(""))
    End Using
    Dim strDoc As String = "C:\Users\local\Desktop\vb testing purpose\test.docx"
    Dim varname As String = "Hi"
    Dim varvalue As String = "Bryan"
    AddDocVar(strDoc, varname, varvalue)
   End Sub

   Public Sub AddDocVar(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal varName As String, ByVal varValue As String)
   Dim mainPart As MainDocumentPart = sender.MainDocumentPart
    Dim settingsPart As DocumentSettingsPart = mainPart.DocumentSettingsPart
    settingsPart.Settings = New Settings(New DocumentVariables(New DocumentVariable() With {.Name = varName, .Val = varValue}))

End Sub
 End Class
```

Comes out a

> exception(System.MissingMemberException: 'Public member 'MainDocumentPart' on type 'String' not found.') in
>
> ```
> Dim mainPart As MainDocumentPart = sender.MainDocumentPart
> ```

Comment: The very first thing you should do is turn `Option Strict On` and then fix the errors that that highlights. That will force you to think about data types and what types your object will be at run-time. It should be fairly obvious that a `String` has no member named `MainDocumentPart` so you're obviously wrong about what data type `sender` will be.  You're probably similarly wrong about various other data types.

Comment: Thank You for your suggestion

Comment: `ByVal sender As Object` should be of type `WordprocessingDocument` in order to have a property named `MainDocumentPart`.

Comment: Very Thanks for your opinion